# PHP How to read XML encoding from DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding, domdocument

I'm using PHPs DOMDocument to output an XML document in a readable format. I want to tell the browser, by setting the character encoding in the response header, how the document is encoded. The XML is declared like this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`
This is my code:

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$loaded = $dom->loadXML($xml_string);
$encoding = $dom->getAttribute('encoding'); //This doesn't work
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

I couldn't find a way to get the encoding "ISO-8859-1" from the XML with a method from `$dom` (DOMDocument). I know I can get it with a regex, but isn't there something like getting the encoding attribute from the DOMDocument object? `$dom->getAttribute('encoding')` didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching for something complex, when it was actually pretty simple: `$encoding = $dom->encoding`.

Comment: The manual (https://php.net/DOMDocument) would have given you that immediately. There's a difference between DOM (with their tags and attributes) and an XML declaration (outside the DOM).